# Golang int to uint8 converison, not detected overflow

Tags: go, type-conversion

I have been making 'A Tour of Go' and occurred on some strange behavior inside the Pic function. It concerns **int -> uint8** conversion. Values of **dx** and **dy** are **256** by default on program execution. So that **x+y** inside the nested for loop goes up to **510**! (255+255)


Nevertheless Golang sees no problem while converting overflowing **x+y** to uint8, but when I change it into some hard-coded value, lets say uint8(321), I immediately obtain an error of an overflow.


Can someone explain me that strange behavior?

```
package main

import "golang.org/x/tour/pic"

func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    canvas := make([][]uint8, dy)

    for y := 0; y < dy; y++ {
        canvas[y] = make([]uint8, dx)
        for x := 0; x < dx; x++ {
            canvas[y][x] = uint8(x+y) // <- here it is
        }
    }
    
    return canvas;
}

func main() {
    pic.Show(Pic)
}
```

Error obtained:

```
go: finding module for package golang.org/x/tour/pic
go: downloading golang.org/x/tour v0.0.0-20200508155540-0608babe047d
go: found golang.org/x/tour/pic in golang.org/x/tour v0.0.0-20200508155540-0608babe047d
./prog.go:11:24: constant 321 overflows uint8

Go build failed.
```

Comment: include the error you talk about .  always include the error, if only to make explanations clearer

Comment: Added the error, for the need of others :) Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the language spec:

> The values of typed constants must always be accurately representable by values of the constant type. The following constant expressions are illegal:
>
> uint(-1)     // -1 cannot be represented as a unit
>
> int(3.14)    // 3.14 cannot be represented as an int

In your case, `x` and `y` are `int`, so `x+y` is also `int`, and `uint8(x+y)` simply truncates the result. However, `uint8(321)` is not valid according to the language spec. However, this is valid:

```
i:=321
x:=uint8(i)
```

Comment: The go compiler can make a good choice about `321` at compile time.  It can't reasonably know if `x+y` overflows - let alone whether that's the intended behavior (overflows are not always errors).

Comment: @DanielFarrell I really like that explanation of compiler decision at the compile time. Makes sense to me